# how to get data from redis or move it to postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, redis, openstreetmap

I am monitoring OpenStreetMap data in real time with a Planet stream master. i am getting this kind of inputs:

```
{ id: '384958919',
  version: '1',
  timestamp: '2015-12-08T09:33:53Z',
  changeset: '35823240',
  uid: '3225472',
  user: 'KozHub',
  action: 'create',
  type: 'way',
  tags: { building: 'yes' },
  nodes: 
   [ { ref: '3883124304', lat: '40.4348805', lon: '-3.7024837' },
     { ref: '3883124307', lat: '40.4348697', lon: '-3.7023227' },
     { ref: '3883124305', lat: '40.4350058', lon: '-3.7023793' },
     { ref: '3883124334', lat: '40.4349997', lon: '-3.7024404' },
     { ref: '3883124306', lat: '40.4349936', lon: '-3.7025014' },
     { ref: '3883124322', lat: '40.4349738', lon: '-3.7024983' },
     { ref: '3883124319', lat: '40.4349400', lon: '-3.7024930' },
     { ref: '3883124304', lat: '40.4348805', lon: '-3.7024837' } ],
  metadata: 
   { id: '35823240',
     created_at: '2015-12-08T09:33:51Z',
     closed_at: '2015-12-08T09:33:54Z',
     open: 'false',
     num_changes: '125',
     user: 'KozHub',
     uid: '3225472',
     min_lat: '40.4348571',
     max_lat: '40.4354335',
     min_lon: '-3.7031081',
     max_lon: '-3.7021086',
     comments_count: '0',
     comment: ' ',
     locale: 'es',
     host: 'https://www.openstreetmap.org/id',
     imagery_used: 'Bing',
     created_by: 'iD 1.8.0' } }
```

For my project i need to collect and save this data. my question is how do i get this data from redis ?

Comment: Try a client like [NodeRedis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis).